# how to save the image to the phone memory(android phone) in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test1 : MonoBehaviour {
public int textureWidth = 400;
public int textureHeight = 400;

public RawImage textureDisplayer;

void Start()
{
    string imageUrl = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    StartCoroutine(LoadImg(imageUrl));
}

void displayImage(Texture2D imgToDisp)
{
    //Resize Image
    textureDisplayer.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(textureWidth, textureHeight);
    textureDisplayer.texture = imgToDisp;
    byte[] bytes = imgToDisp.EncodeToPNG();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("image", bytes);
}


IEnumerator LoadImg(string url)
{
    yield return null;
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    displayImage(www.texture);
}


}
```

here i am trying to save the impToDisp to my phone memory.
in my code i am able to load the image.

i need to save that loaded image to my phone memory.how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to consider using MemoryStream.

for example:

```
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                myBitmap.Save(ms, myBitmap.RawFormat);
            }
```

see this example in the Unity3d forums:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/563113/saving-png-image-to-memorystream-causes-access-vio.html

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please include snippets of the referenced code in your answer, so the answer can stand alone even in the (unlikely) case that the linked site goes offline.